# Doctrine update query with equal operator as set

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have problems to set a value based on a statement

I want to **activate** a specific `uc` and **deactivate** all other `ucs`.

`(uc.collection = :collectionId)` should return true or false so it is correctly handled.

QueryBuilder:

```
    $queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $queryBuilder->update('TestBundle:UserCollection', 'uc')
        ->set('uc.active', '(uc.collection = :collectionId)')
        ->where('uc.user = :userId');

    $queryBuilder->setParameter('collectionId', $collectionId);
    $queryBuilder->setParameter('userId', $userId);
```

Output DQL:

```
UPDATE TestBundle:UserCollection uc 
SET uc.active = (uc.collection = :collectionId) WHERE uc.user = :userId
```

getSQL Error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 81: Error: Expected 
Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got '='
```

Here the SQL I want:

```
UPDATE user_collections AS uc SET uc.active = (uc.idCollections = 1)
WHERE uc.idUsers = 74
```

Comment: Erm, why would you use parenthesis at the first place?

Comment: without I get this error `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 80: Error: Expected end of string, got '='`

Comment: There is a reason you get that. I will write an answer now, for the sake of readability, which might help you...

Comment: without `(` the DQL looks wrong `... SET uc.active = c.id = :collectionId WHERE ...`

Comment: did add some more information and the SQL i want

Comment: Ah, ok, I reread you question and it's not what I thought it was. Let me think a bit and I'll return to you with suggestion :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88806/discussion-between-alexander-schranz-and-jovan-perovic).

Answer (score 1):

Try setting it up via `expr()->eq(...)` expression:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->update('TestBundle:UserCollection', 'uc')
    ->set('uc.active', $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('uc.collection', ':collectionId'))
    ->where('uc.user = :userId');

$queryBuilder->setParameter('collectionId', $collectionId);
$queryBuilder->setParameter('userId', $userId);
```

Comment: did not work the DQL looks also not correct  
`... SET uc.active = collection.id = :collectionId WHERE ...`  
`[Syntax Error] line 0, col 80: Error: Expected end of string, got '='`